# "post" method to communicate directly with a server

Tags: python, wordpress, urllib2, urllib

Just started with python not long ago, and I'm learning to use "post" method to communicate directly with a server. A fun script I'm working on right now is to post comments on wordpress. The script does post comments on my local site, but I don't know why it raises HTTP Error 404 which means page not found. Here's my code, please help me find what's wrong:

```
import urllib2
import urllib

url='http://localhost/wp-comments-post.php'
user_agent='Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)'  
values={'author':'Urllib Test', 'email':'test@test.com',  'url':'', 'comment':'This is a test comment from python', 'submit':'Post Comment', 'comment_post_ID': '1', 'comment_parent':'0'}  
headers={'User-Agent': user_agent}

data=urllib.urlencode(values)  
req=urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)

urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

Comment: `>` is for block quotes - remove them, select the code and use CTRL-K to format the code properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use [Mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/). It will simplify your life.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation, some online wordpress blogs do work with above code, still don't know why it doesn't work in my local site.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Mechanize does make things much easier, and I also found what the problem is finally. Check it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653086/whats-the-difference-between-browser-posting-and-program-posting

Answer (score 0):

why is there a 'url' in your values ? did you try without it ?

then, try replacing localhost with 127.0.0.1 (if localhost is not in your hosts file). 
Are you on windows or linux ?

Comment: You can leave a website which will be the link your name directs to when the comments show up, it can be blank. "Author" and "email" must be filled. 
I'm on windows XP. I've replaced localhost with 127.0.0.1, and the problem remains the same. 
The problem is the script does post comments every time it runs, but I don't know why it raises error 404.